# Comments that fail to post start the "You can only comment every 5 seconds" timer

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

I tried to leave a comment similar to the following:

> @User: Stuff. @All: Things.

Naturally I got an error popup telling me I can't @notify multiple people.  I quickly removed the second `@` and tried to submit the comment again, resulting in:

> You can only post a comment every 5 seconds; timer reset

(Exact wording may be slightly different).

The problem is that the first version of the comment wasn't actually posted due to the error.  The delay is unnecessary in this case and pretty frustrating (for something that only lasts 5 seconds :P).

I believe I've also encountered this in other situations, but my memory is imperfect and I can't really test it.  Something to do with flagging and commenting, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103037/comments-that-fail-to-post-start-the-you-can-only-comment-every-5-seconds-time/)

Comment: Found [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69944/comment-length-validation-and-rate-limiting-bug). It seems to be the same as my complaint, but was misunderstood and closed as a dupe of an I-don't-understand-"timer reset".  [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38947/get-you-can-only-comment-every-15-seconds-error-erroneously/38957#38957) says it too, and Jeff doesn't address it, again appearing to misunderstand.

Comment: Well... I'll leave this up as it's the official response for now. If that ever changes, I'll update this answer. You could ask again in the main meta as this affects all sites.

Comment: It's finally been fixed :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103037/comments-that-fail-to-post-start-the-you-can-only-comment-every-5-seconds-time/

Comment: @MatthewRead If it's fixed, can you accept this answer?  Community poked this post this morning, so I figured I'd pass on the message :)

Comment: @DaveMcClelland, I believe that if this answer had some upvotes it'd be enough for the not-poking filter... so feel free to give it one :)

Comment: @JuanManuel Good point - done

Comment: Thanks @Dave, accepted.